# How to save a powershell function that takes a paramter

Tags: powershell, shell

I have a powershell function that I run that tells me how long any command I run takes. It looks like this.

```
(Measure-Command {  <command> | Out-Default }).TotalSeconds | ForEach-Object { $totalMinutes = [math]::Floor($_ / 60); $remainingSeconds = $_ % 60; Write-Host "Time Elapsed: $totalMinutes Minutes, $remainingSeconds seconds" }
```

I want to be able to run this like this:

```
c:\files> timer <command>
```

I want to save that function to my profile. I know where my profile file is and how to edit it, but I do not know how to save this function to my profile so that I can just execute as I described `timer <command>` like for example `timer py --version`. Can you please show me what the proper syntax would be?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a wrapper function around `Measure-Command` that takes a scriptblock as argument, note that in order for this to work you must call your function using the syntax: `timer {...}` (the curly braces are mandatory).

```bash
function timer {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [scriptblock] $Command
    )

    end {
        $span = [timespan]::FromMinutes((Measure-Command { & $Command | Out-Default }).TotalMinutes)
        Write-Host ('Time Elapsed: {0:D2} minutes, {1:D2} seconds.' -f $span.Minutes, $span.Seconds)
    }
}
```

Example of how to use it:

```
timer { 0..10 | ForEach-Object { $_; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200 } }
```

Would produce the following output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Time Elapsed: 00 minutes, 02 seconds.
```

**Note that due to the use of `Out-Default`, the output from the scriptblock cannot be captured.**

---

An alternative if you wanted to capture the output from your timer function is to store [`datetime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-7.0) before the scriptblock execution and then calculating the time difference after the execution is completed:

```
function timer {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory)]
        [scriptblock] $Command
    )

    end {
        $now = [datetime]::Now
        & $Command
        $span = [datetime]::Now - $now
        Write-Host ('Time Elapsed: {0:D2} minutes, {1:D2} seconds.' -f $span.Minutes, $span.Seconds)
    }
}
```

Now the output can be captured without problems:

```
$capture = timer { 0..10 | ForEach-Object { $_; Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the functionality where *all* you need to do is just add the word `timer` as a prefix you can do this:

```
function timer {
  param (
      [string]$Command,
      [string[]]$Arguments
  )

  $fullCommand = "$Command $Arguments"
  $startTime = Get-Date
  Invoke-Expression $fullCommand
  $endTime = Get-Date

  $elapsedTime = $endTime - $startTime
  $totalSeconds = [math]::Floor($elapsedTime.TotalSeconds)
  $totalMinutes = [math]::Floor($totalSeconds / 60)
  $remainingSeconds = $totalSeconds % 60

  Write-Host "Time Elapsed: $totalMinutes Minutes, $remainingSeconds seconds"
  }
```

The output looks like this:

```
PS C:\files> timer sleep 5
Time Elapsed: 0 Minutes, 5 seconds
PS C:\files>
```

Another way to do this but you'll need to wrap the actual command as a string is :

```
function timer {
  param (
      [string]$Command
  )

  $startTime = Get-Date
  Invoke-Expression $Command
  $endTime = Get-Date

  $elapsedTime = $endTime - $startTime
  $totalSeconds = [math]::Floor($elapsedTime.TotalSeconds)
  $totalMinutes = [math]::Floor($totalSeconds / 60)
  $remainingSeconds = $totalSeconds % 60

  Write-Host "Time Elapsed: $totalMinutes Minutes, $remainingSeconds seconds"
  }
```

The output looks like this:

```
PS C:\files> timer "sleep 5"
Time Elapsed: 0 Minutes, 5 seconds
PS C:\files>
```